# R package requiring dll

Tags: r, dll, r-package

I am now trying to use an R package named [gepR](http://yliu.eng.wayne.edu/research/gepR_demo_A.html). I followed instructions provided by the demo and encountered an error saying that: LoadLibrary failure: the specified module could not be found.

I have tried many solutions posted online, including edit environment variable of the system, put gepR.dll in the system directory (like C:/Windows/system), etc. But none of them works. So I think the error message is not about gepR.dll but some other files. I realized it may be caused by some missing files but I am not sure about how to do the troubleshooting.

Error message:

Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : unable to load shared object: .../my/working/directory:
LoadLibrary failure: the specified module could not be found.

Really sorry that I know merely a little about how computers work and really need your help. Thanks!

Comment: What code are you running exactly that triggers the error? What is the exact error message you are getting? How did you install the package? Were there any error or warnings during install? Did you run the `gep_load_dll()` command? According to the link you provided it says it will look for the grepR.dll in your current working directory.  It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick    Thanks for reply. I installed the package completely following the instructions in the demo. First install devtools then install_github. The error occurs when I ran the command $gep_load_dll()$. The message says that:                                            
     Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : unable to load shared object: .../my/working/directory:LoadLibrary failure: the specified module could not be found. There is no warnings or error when installing and gepR.dll is right under my working directory.

Comment: Please edit important information into the question itself so it can be properly formatted. You said you put the dll into the C:/Windows/system directory, but by default it says it looks in the working directory. Check your working director with `getwd()` and make sure the file is there.

Comment: @MrFlick By system directory, I meant I had seen solutions saying that the computer search the .dll file in a certain order so worthy to try putting that .dll under system directory to solve the problem. The gepR.dll is also in my working directory.

Comment: Does `file.exists("gepR.dll")` return TRUE?

Comment: @MrFlick Yes, it returns TRUE

Comment: Well, the github hasn't been updated in three years. It's possible it just doesn't work anymore. You can file an issue with the author at the github site. https://github.com/profyliu/gepR

Comment: @MrFlick yeah..I noticed that, too. Now I may need to implement the algorithm on my own.. Anyway, thanks so much for your help!!